# C - Not reading the integer variable in GetProfileInt() function in windows 7

Tags: capl

I am using the getprofileInt() function in C for CAPL scripting, but here it is not taking the variable value defined in ini file. Its taking only default value. This is my code:

```
int ESPV_hex,BCM1var,BCM1Hex;

Gateway_72_msgrequest()
{
  BCM1var =getProfileInt("CONFIG_SIGNAL","BCM1_ASSUEN_TEMP_UNGEF",0xFF,"SIGNALvalue_list.INI");
  write("BCM signal input value %d",BCM1var);
  write("BCM signal input value %x",BCM1var);
  Gateway_72_Dlc8.byte(7)=BCM1var;
  output(Gateway_72_Dlc8);
}
```

---

```
; File: SIGNALvalue_list.ini
; Contains the list of all Signals values.

[CONFIG_SIGNAL]
BCM1_Waschwasser_Sensor=10
```

Comment: can you show your code here

Comment: @NuOne T Attygalle i have posted the code

Comment: Don't spam tags this is not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The name of the function is `GetProfileInt`, not `getProfileInt` as you have it in your code
- `GetProfileInt` only takes three parameters, whereas you pass four parameters, so the signature is not compatible
- `GetProfileInt` only works with the `win.ini` file. You might prefer using [`GetPrivateProfileInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofileint#parameters) which lets you specify the `.ini` file to use
- If you are using `GetPrivateProfileInt` to specify the `.ini` file, you really should specify the full file path to the `.ini` file. Otherwise the system will only look for it in the Windows directory.

Comment: Also `"BCM1_ASSUEN_TEMP_UNGEF"` does not exist in `SIGNALvalue_list.ini` as shown in the question in any case.